Sub-url redirect on S3 static hosted website
I have a static website hosted in S3, a domain hosted on route 53, and used a CloudFront distribution.
What is the proper way to setup a sub page URL redirection to a different resource?
e.g. http://s3Hostedsite.net/product/24 to be redirected only to a different website while keeping main traffic to the S3 website.

Perhaps redirect in a CloudFront Function, example here.

Best way for this is to use CloudFront Function as you're already using cloudfront
•   Navigate to CloudFront > Functions.
•   Create a new function that checks the URL path and redirects specific paths

for example for your case:
function handler(event) {
var request = event.request;
var uri = request.uri;

if (uri.startsWith("/product/24")) {
    return {
        statusCode: 302,
        statusDescription: 'Found',
        headers: {
            'location': { 
                value: 'newurl' 
            }
        }
    };
}

return request;}

and the end do not forget to add it to the viewer request of your cloudfront distribution.
for more details feel free to check AWS Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/service_code_examples_cloudfront_functions_examples.html
